# gradient computation for neural ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, machine-learning

I was reading the paper on Neural ODEs ([here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07366)) and was wondering if anyone could offer some insight on calculation of the gradient of the loss function.

If we are only considering 2 time points, $t_0,t_1$, I understand how the adjoint method works. However, what confuses me is when the loss function involves multiple time points, say $t_0,t_1,t_2$.

The paper says (on p. 15) that the adjoint step for each intervals $[t_1,t_2]$ and $[t_0,t_1]$ can be performed and that the obtained gradients can be summed. I find this confusing as well as Figure 2 of the paper (page 2).

Using the paper's notation, I understand that $\mathbf{a}(t) = \frac{dL}{d \mathbf{z}(t)}$ and $\mathbf{a}_t(t) = \frac{dL}{dt(t)}$ need to be computed first on the interval $[t_1,t_2]$ then use these results, together with an adjustment of $\frac{dL}{d \mathbf{z}(t_1)}, \frac{dL}{dt(t_1)}$, to compute the quantities $\mathbf{a}(t),\mathbf{a}_t(t)$ on the
interval $[t_0,t_1]$. Specifically, according to [the code in this blog](https://msurtsukov.github.io/Neural-ODE/), on the time interval $[t_0,t_1]$, the initial conditions have to be $\mathbf{a}(t_1) + \frac{dL}{d \mathbf{z}(t_1)}$ and $\mathbf{a}_t(t_1)-\frac{dL}{d t(t_1)}$ . Can anyone help me understand/show mathematically why the adjustments to the gradient computation have to be done like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use e.g. integral loss functions distributed on the whole domain you may want to take a look at [Dissecting Neural ODEs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.08071) which has code implementation here
[torchdyn](https://github.com/DiffEqML/torchdyn)